# AWS Elatic Beanstalk "Checking instance health" takes too long time

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I deploy new version to environment, it takes about 6~8 minutes to complete. My application is a light one, it takes about 2~3 seconds to launch(response OK to healthchecking request).

This is whole steps:

1. PR is merged.
2. application.zip(for aws eb) is built from Github Actions.
3. application.zip is uploaded by eb cli.
4. Event: "Batch {N}: Starting application deployment command execution."
5. Event: "Batch {N}: Registering instance(s) with the load balancer and waiting for them to be healthy."
   Every steps above takes less than a minute, but after step 5, I have to wait more than 3 minutes.
6. Repeat step 4 until every rolling update is done.

[image]
[image]

My configurations:

[image]
[image]

I'm using rolling update because my service deployed quite frequently and I don't want any downtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you Application is very light weight then choose Rolling updates and deployments and change Deployment policy as All at once this will deploy your code with in a minute [Application may Have ms down time during the traffic changing] or if you want to still use the Rolling update keep the details as like below mentioned

Batch size:
30%
Rolling update type: Rolling Based on Health
Batch size:
1
Minimum capacity:
1

Comment: I edited question with my configurations.